# Build backwards-compatible, cross-architecture project in modern Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, centos

My development environment is Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64. I'm working on a C++ codebase that, for maximum support among users, needs to be built in a CentOS 6 i386 (-like) environment. Specifically, it depends on its versions of GCC and the system libraries.

My current solution is to run the build in a CentOS VM (in VirtualBox), sharing the codebase via a shared folder. It works pretty well, but a completely local build would be better.

Is it possible to do this in Ubuntu? I'd prefer a way that allows me to keep my system up-to-date in the foreseeable future, without affecting the build. I know this is possible with e.g. Mock in Fedora, but that doesn't work well on Ubuntu.

By the way, would a newer version of GCC be a problem? Would it be a benefit? For example, with regards to faster compilation or better optimization?

Comment: I've already tried just installing the i386 versions of the libraries from apt, but some don't want to exist side-by-side with the x86_64 versions I need to actually run my system.

Comment: Would you consider using CentOS via Docker to be better, or no improvement over your current CentOS VM?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't know much about Docker. From what I've heard it's virtualisation light, taking only what you need? That sounds at least a bit better than a full VM.

Comment: Yeah, Docker might be a lighter-weight, more reproducible way to do it than a regular VM.  I'd give it a try.  Or you could install an old version of GCC (and more to the point, glibc) on Ubuntu to be compatible with CentOS 6.

Comment: In the end I manually fixed one or two libraries that wouldn't install as both amd64 and i386, added compile options to force 32-bits, and just compiled the project with the newer system libraries and GCC. But that's not really an answer, just an alternate solution.